# Verify if $n$ dimensional spheres intersect

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry

Consider $x_1,\dots,x_n$ vectors lying in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, consider positive numbers $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$. Consider $n$ spheres with center as $x_i$ and radii $\alpha_i$. How do I check the set of solutions to the set of equations
\begin{align}
||x-x_i||_2 = \alpha_i~,~ \forall i
\end{align}
is non-empty. Is this problem studied in literature?

Comment: Why can't you take an arbitrary $x_0$ and use $\alpha_i = |x_0-x_i|$?

Comment: Another even more brutal solution : let M= maximal distance $\|x_i-x_j\|$. Then take all $\alpha_i=M$...

Comment: @VasilyMitch I see your point, thanks. This is not what I actually wanted. Let me rewrite the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is well-studied. For example, you can read [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.873.3930&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

One of the methods works like this:
Rewrite your equation as
$$
2x_ix = x^2 +x_i^2 - \alpha_i^2.
$$
Find $x$ in form $x=ru+v$, where $r=x^2$, $u$ is the solution of $2x_iu=1$, $v$ is the solution of $2x_iv=x_i^2-\alpha_i^2$. Then
$$
r=x^2=(ru+v)^2=r^2u^2+2uv r+v^2
$$
is a quadratic equation on $r$. If this equation has roots, then your $n$ spheres have a common point.

Comment: Does this work for vectors?

Comment: It is vector equations